Why WM_INPUT is so slow?
I was trying to make a simple dummy window manager in windows. When I tried using WM_KEY*/WM_SYSKEY* it ran perfectly fine and responsive. But when I use WM_INPUT, as shown in code below, after using the keyboard a lot, everything slows down horribly and eventually Not Responding screen comes up and stops the program. The code is written in a single file in C style, but the compiler is g++, just in case I need some C++ features. For the sake of this question, assume it is C.
#ifdef __MINGW32__
#   define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif // __MINGW32__

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    bool keys[256];
} KEYBOARD;

typedef struct{
    bool keys[5];
    int16_t deltaWheel;
    int deltaX;
    int deltaY;
} MOUSE;

KEYBOARD Keyboard;
MOUSE Mouse;

const int ScreenHeight = 1080;
const int ScreenWidth = 1920;
uint32_t* ScreenBitmap;
BITMAPINFO BitmapInfo = {};

bool Running;

void SetPixel(int x, int y, uint32_t color){
    if(x >= 0 & y >= 0 & x < ScreenWidth & y < ScreenHeight){
        ScreenBitmap[y * ScreenWidth + x] = color;
    }
}

uint32_t GetPixel(int x, int y){
    if(x >= 0 & y >= 0 & x < ScreenWidth & y < ScreenHeight){
        return ScreenBitmap[y * ScreenWidth + x];
    } else return 0;
}

void DrawRectangle(int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2, uint32_t color){
    int maxX = X2 >= ScreenWidth ? ScreenWidth - 1 : X2;
    int maxY = Y2 >= ScreenHeight ? ScreenHeight - 1: Y2;
    int minX = X1 < 0 ? 0 : X1;
    int minY = X2 < 0 ? 0 : Y1;

    for(int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++){
        for(int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++){
            SetPixel(x, y, color);
        }
    }
}

void UpdateScreenBitmap(){
    DrawRectangle(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0x00000000);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND WindowHandle, uint32_t Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam){
    switch(Message){

        case WM_CREATE:{
            ScreenBitmap = (uint32_t*) VirtualAlloc(0, ScreenHeight * ScreenWidth * 4, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = ScreenWidth;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -ScreenHeight;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        } break;

        case WM_NCDESTROY:{
            Running = false;
        } break;

        case WM_PAINT:{
            InvalidateRect(WindowHandle, 0, 0);
            SetDIBitsToDevice(GetDC(WindowHandle), 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0, 0, 0, ScreenHeight, ScreenBitmap, &BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
            ValidateRect(WindowHandle, 0);
        } break;

        case WM_INPUT:{
            uint32_t RawInputSize = sizeof(RAWINPUT);
            RAWINPUT RawInput = {};
            GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)LParam, RID_INPUT, &RawInput, &RawInputSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
            if(RawInput.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD){
                RAWKEYBOARD kb = RawInput.data.keyboard;
                Keyboard.keys[kb.MakeCode] = kb.Flags == 0 ? true : false;
            } else if(RawInput.header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE){
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    if(RawInput.data.mouse.usButtonFlags == (0b01 << 2*i)) Mouse.keys[i] = true;
                    if(RawInput.data.mouse.usButtonFlags == (0b10 << 2*i)) Mouse.keys[i] = false;
                }
                Mouse.deltaWheel = RawInput.data.mouse.usButtonData;
                Mouse.deltaX = RawInput.data.mouse.lLastX;
                Mouse.deltaY = RawInput.data.mouse.lLastY;
            }
        } break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(WindowHandle, Message, WParam, LParam);
}

//int WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance, HINSTANCE PrevInstance, LPSTR ComandLine, int ShowComand){
int main(){

    if(true){
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
        freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
        freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
    }

    WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "Window Class Name";
    WindowClass.hInstance = (HINSTANCE) GetModuleHandle(0);
    RegisterClass(&WindowClass);

    HWND WindowHandle = CreateWindow(WindowClass.lpszClassName, 0, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0, 0, WindowClass.hInstance, 0);

    RAWINPUTDEVICE RawInputDevice[2];

    RawInputDevice[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    RawInputDevice[0].usUsage = 0x02;
    RawInputDevice[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
    RawInputDevice[0].hwndTarget = WindowHandle;

    RawInputDevice[1].usUsagePage = 0x01;
    RawInputDevice[1].usUsage = 0x06;
    RawInputDevice[1].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;
    RawInputDevice[1].hwndTarget = WindowHandle;

    RegisterRawInputDevices(RawInputDevice, 2, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICE));

    ShowWindow(WindowHandle, 1);
    SetWindowPos(WindowHandle, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    ShowCursor(false);

    Running = true;
    while(Running){
        MSG Message = {};
        while(PeekMessage(&Message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&Message);
            DispatchMessage(&Message);
        }
        UpdateScreenBitmap();
        SetDIBitsToDevice(GetDC(WindowHandle), 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0, 0, 0, ScreenHeight, ScreenBitmap, &BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    }

    return 0;
}


Issue is probably just Message Queue filling up due to unprocessed messages. But I am doing barely any processing in WM_INPUT branch. but the documentation or google doesn't explain it I tried to find something relevant in SDL source code, but failed.

What is InputHandler? What does it do?

@Someprogrammerdude it doesn't exist for this question, it was from earlier and forgot to remove

By the way, there should be tools where you can see the number of messages in the queue (perhaps even the task manager can show it?)  to help you understand if that's the problem. Besides just comment out all the handling and do nothing in the WM_INPUT handler to see if it makes things better. If it does then add back one line at a time to see what causes the problem.

@Someprogrammerdude How do you use task manager for that? removing WM_INPUT didn't work, neither did passing it to DefWindowProc().

If it doesn't work when you don't have WM_INPUT then that's an indicator that the problem is somewhere else.
